# Setting the value of a javascript variable if null

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am setting 3 global variables to the values of my posts meta data.  I would like to understand how to set a default value for each variable if none is returned.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var JprettyAd = '<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyAd', true); ?>';
var JprettyName = '<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyName', true); ?>';
var JprettyLink = '<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyLink', true); ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: If 'none is returned' from..? [tag:php] or [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Your 3'rd variable value definitely has syntax errors..

Comment: You can't, if php returns null, the value will be `'null'`, a string is never false or null, unless the php returns an empty string. If the ouput looks like this: `var JprettyAd = '';`, you could can simply add the default operator: `var JprettyAd = '<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyAd', true); ?>' || 'defaultString';`

Comment: better run that php output through `json_encode()`, unless you enjoy having your JS code injected and killed due to syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

```
var JprettyAd = <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyAd', true); ?> ||
    'someDefault';
```

Note this will use the `'someDefault'` value if PHP returns any "falsey" value: `null`, `undefined`, `''`, `0`, or `NaN`.

See the section labeled "Default Assignments" [here](http://www.punkchip.com/2010/05/javascript-shorthand/).

Comment: You should quote the `<php..>` otherwise it may be interpreted as a variable name and error out. Unless you're sure that the value is a number.

Comment: Thank you. With a small tweak this works perfectly. All that was need was to add single quotes around php and change the key quotes to double.

Answer (score 0):

get_post_meta returns an empty array if not found so you can do

```
<?php $response = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyAd', true); ?>
var JprettyAd = <?php echo ($response ?: $defaultValue); ?>;
```

because empty arrays in php are evaluated as false